# jenkins copy artefacts - copy from upstream job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

The copy artefacts plugin is quite flexible in allowing the build from another job to copy the artefacts from but it still requires the Job name to be hardcoded.

What i am looking for is a way to copy artefacts from any upstream job and build rather than a hardcoded job and a dynamic build.

Comment: I think you can use Parametrized build plugin and pass job name as a parameter name. Do you try this?

Comment: I had already thought of this but what do i do next. I am not sure if Jenkins allows some sort of if else build step does it?

Comment: When you add parameter e.g. JOB_NAME and when you trigger run job you should pass current job parameter.

Comment: @krynio Thanks, it works!! please add an answer so i can accept.